# How to debug javascript in cshtml

Tags: javascript, c#, google-chrome, debugging, razor

I have a .cshtml file of the following format (apologies if my JavaScript terminology is a bit loose)

```
@model SomeViewModel
@{ Response.ContentType = "application/x-javascript"; }

$(function() {
         // Javascript event handler code here
    }
});

$(function ($) {
        // Javascript JQuery.DatePicker extensions here
    }
});
```

I am fairly sure that there is a bug that needs fixing in the second JS block, but I am struggling to debug it.  I am using Chrome.

The picture is somewhat complicated by the fact that there exists a `MyDatepicker.js` file elsewhere in the solution with the exact same javascript, and a `MyDatepicker.min.js` which appears at runtime and can be debugged (just about).

So

- what is happening to the js code in the cshtml - may i ignore it?
- how do I ensure a non-minified version of the javascript gets loaded
- how do I establish where the minified version of the
  script comes from?

---

following the advice given below, I find the following class.

```
public class MyDatePickerController : Controller
{
    // GET: /jquery.mydatepicker.js
    [Minify]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MyDatePickerViewModel model = new MyDatePickerViewModel(); 

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

which appears to explain how the javascript gets minified.

Given that there is a MyDatePicker.js file **as well as** the code in the .cshtml file, I am still unsure which copy of the javascript gets loaded.  I will edit one of them, take out the `minify` and see which gets loaded.

---

Now that I have located the reason the script was being minified I have been able to establish for certain that the javascript being executed was that from the razor file (`.cshtml`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your bundleconfig file, MyDatepicker.min.js might be bundled with other js files.

Comment: I have 2 BundleConfig.cs files in the project, one under `App_Start`, the other under Mvc\App_Start.  `MyDatePicker.min.js` & `MyDatePicker.js` are not in either of those.  Is that enough to conclude that the .js file is not being loaded, and that the RAZR version is?

Comment: check your _Layout.cshtml as well.

Comment: Press Ctrl+Shift+ F and search for MyDatepicker.
You can find all the files with "MyDatepicker" in the solution.

Comment: thanks for your help.  By locating the controller I was able to un-minify and hence start debugging with confidence.